# excel merged cells copy paste issue

Tags: excel, vba

copy the merged cell and paste into the unmerged cell causing merging of pasted area also.
example: A1,B1 are merged together. now I copied this range and pasted in D1. since the copied range is merge format, the pasted area becoming like D1:E1. D1, E1 are merged after pasting data.
I want to paste data only in D1. how to solve this issue using VBA

Comment: Could you show what you got so far? It seems that you copiede the cells and not the value.

Comment: the manual copy paste is happening in  one of my Excel sheet. when copy paste merged cell , I don't want merged the pasted area. the pasting has to limit to single cell.

Comment: You cant change the behavior of the excel copy-paste, you can copy the values like @Lawrence shows it or you unmerge the cells after the copy-paste with a macro.

Comment: my excel template users will do copy paste activity. the copy paste is randomly happens, not the fixed area. so I thought if any work around available to fix this.

Comment: I dont think there is a viable option to to that. You could check the Change events of excel, but they look for every chage that happens in the workbook but i dont think its a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get text of area A1:B1, then set Range("D1").value=the context you got.

```
Dim TmpStr = Range("A1:B1").Value
Range("D1").value = TmpStr
```

Or, You can put the text in clipbox by VBA, then select the target cell where you want to paste.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my case is different. user will do manual copy paste in excel. if user try to copy merged area cells and paste in unmerged cell, the destinations also merging. I don't want to merge the destination cells. the pasting has to apply in single cell only .how to fix this.

Comment: Without VBA, double click then copy the text ,then paste.

Comment: Or you can create one macro do copying text into clipbox. then assign shortcut for it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the upper-left most cell in your merged range

i.e. for merged range of cells A20:C21

```
cells(20,1).copy
```

Then go paste

```
cells(25,1).pastespecial paste:=xlPasteValues
```